# Joe the incremental car pusher

Tags: functions, arithmetic

Whenever I call my friend Joe, he pushes a car down a road. (Assume the road is flat and has no other cars on it, and that the car has no brakes.)

The car Joe's pushing has to cover a very precise distance by the end of the day.

At the start of the day, Joe and I have to agree on the frequency at which I'll call him until he's reached the preagreed distance, and the distance he'll push the car by every time I call him.  (BTW, Joe is the name of my computer program's function).

**Given:**

- the total distance that Joe needs to cover.
- the total amount of time that Joe has to take to cover that distance.
- that the frequency at which I will call Joe is arbitrarily chosen before he starts pushing the car, but stays the same until he's reached the preagreed distance.

**Find the equation that will give me the distance Joe has to push the car by every time I call him.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the day be 24 hours; call him $f$ times an hour; let the total distance be $d$; let the push each time be $p$; then the equation relating everything is $d=24pf$. Solving for $p$ you get $p=d/(24f)$.

Comment: Correct! Thanks Gerry.